# Why std::optional::value_or dont have a specialization for default ctor types?

Tags: c++

```
std::optional<Class> a;
a.value_or( Class() ).GetMember();
```

Why cant we do this like:

```
a.value_or().GetMember();
```

Can standard specialize `value_or` on a default constructible basis?

Comment: Good question. The slightly facetious answer is that it's not there since nobody has convinced the C++ standards committee of its necessity.

Comment: If anything, such a function would probably be better called `value_or_default()`. Having nothing (not even an argument) follow the `or` is just... weird? It certainly doesn't read well.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: So you don't think this would be any weirder than the `[]` operator of `std::map` that actually inserts a value if it's not there?

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't. Only one of these would be a failed attempt at expressing the effects of something in English.

Comment: You can always do `a.value_or({}).GetMember();`,

Comment: The bit that annoys me is the parameter is constructed for the value_or, even if it isn't used.  Small annoyance for cheap default objects; big annoyance for expensive default objects -- which if that is the case `value_or` is probably the wrong route to go for expensive objects.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy, unfortunately that won't do. Compiler is not able to infer the argument's type.

Comment: [The original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html#rationale.value_or)'s an interesting read, though it doesn't seem to address this specifically, which is a shame. It _is_, however, quite cautious about recommending people lean on `value_or` too much in the first place (it's only a template for reasons of optimisation), and the section about it in the proposal is chock full of alternative suggestions for users, so I'm not shocked its usability wasn't enhanced further.

Comment: If you start allowing `a.value_or()`, it should become like `emplace`, accept any number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this `value_or` doesn't have this option and I agree with with Max Langhof's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035592/why-stdoptionalvalue-or-dont-have-a-specialization-for-default-ctor-types#comment104314365_59035592) that it should be a separate function `value_or_default`.

Nevertheless, as Eljay pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035592/why-stdoptionalvalue-or-dont-have-a-specialization-for-default-ctor-types#comment104314664_59035592), the code from the question might cause problems for classes with expensive default construction. In cases when the `optional` does not carry a value, we don't want the default constructor to be called.

I've put together a little workaround for that particular case:

```cpp
struct default_constructor_t {
  explicit default_constructor_t() = default;
};

inline constexpr default_constructor_t default_constructor{};

class Class {
...
  Class(default_constructor_t) : Class{} {}
...
};

int GetMember(std::optional<Class> Object) {
  return Object.value_or(default_constructor).GetMember();
}
```

In this solution, you need to add an additional implicit constructor to your class. This solution is also lazy. It will call default constructor *only* if `optional` doesn't have a value.

**UPD**:
After a bit of thinking, I believe that I came up with a bit more generic solution that will work even with types the developer can't modify. And even if one has this ability, less code is better, right?

```
struct DefaultConstructed {
  template <class T> operator T() const {
    return T();
  }
};

constexpr DefaultConstructed Default;

class Class {
...
};

int GetMember(std::optional<Class> Object) {
  return Object.value_or(Default).GetMember();
}
```

This solution uses conversion operator instead of implicit construction. Special object named `Default` can be converted (so to speak) to any type by calling this type's default constructor. It also retains the nice property of the original solution to be lazy.

Comment: Your solution is _longer_ than the original code!! Even if you only consider the callsite! What's the purpose of that?

Comment: It won't construct the actual object *unless* the optional doesn't carry the value. In cases, when default construction is not free, it makes total sense to be not pleased with it. Additionally, the second solution is added once to one header and can be used with **any** type whatsoever. I think writing `Default` instead of `TypeName()` is not that much longer.

Comment: Ah, right, I'll give you that. It didn't occur to me that anyone was focusing on that problem because the question doesn't really say what the OP's after and so I assumed it was about code length ;) Might be a good idea to expand the start of this answer to clarify which problem you're fixing. But yes this is a good solution to that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the answer to include that bit of information.